# Multi-module project, gradle and bintray

Tags: java, gradle, bintray

I have multi-module Java project ([Jodd](http://jodd.org)). Main module, i.e. the root project is **not** java project. Only large subset of submodules are java projects:

```
root
  |-- jodd-core
  |-- jodd-bean
  ...
```

I wanted to apply bintray plugin. So first thing I did is:

#### 1. Apply bintray to just java submodules.

This worked fine, except, since bintray is not enabled from the root; I am not able to invoke just:

```
gradle bintrayUpload
```

since this task does not exist in the root. Then I tried this:

#### 2. Apply bintray to all modules, including the root.

This worked, except now on the bintray I have an empty package for the root, that does not have any file.

#### Question

What would be the right way to upload to bintray? I think I would go with the solution 1 and create my own custom task that will depend on bintrayUpload tasks on all Java modules. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Solution #1 seems the way to go. Ive created task `bintray` that depends on all `bintrayUpload` task from submodules that have something to publish.